# .NET C# - Google AdWords API Authorization Issue "USER_PERMISSION_DENIED"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-ads-api

I've been trying to connect to the Google AdWords API, and I succeeded
with receiving information from only one client.
Everytime I use a different ClientCustomerId, it throws an exception with
an inner detail - "USER_PERMISSION_DENIED".

(Written in Web.config `<add key="ClientCustomerId" value="val-val-val"/>`)

Only one client works though. I have no idea with differences they have, they're all same. the only difference is that the working client is the first in my client list.

Here is my code for receiving campaign information:

```
            AdWordsUser user = new AdWordsUser();
        CampaignService campaignService =
(CampaignService)user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201506.CampaignService);
        Selector selector = new Selector();
        selector.fields = new string[] { "Id", "Name", "Status"};
        selector.paging = new Paging();

        int offset = 0;
        int pageSize = 500;

        CampaignPage page = new CampaignPage();

        try
        {
            do
            {
                selector.paging.startIndex = offset;
                selector.paging.numberResults = pageSize;
                string result = "";
                // Get the campaigns.
                page = campaignService.get(selector);

                // Display the results.
                if (page != null && page.entries != null)
                {
                    int i = offset;
                    foreach (Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.v201506.Campaign campaign in page.entries)
                    {
                        result += string.Format("{0}) Campaign with id = '{1}', name = '{2}' and status = '{3}'" +
                          " was found.", i + 1, campaign.id, campaign.name, campaign.status);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                Response.Write(result);
                offset += pageSize;
            } while (offset < page.totalNumEntries);

            int a = page.totalNumEntries;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new System.ApplicationException("Failed to retrieve campaigns", e);
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you authenticating?

Comment: I'm using OAuth2 for authentication.

Comment: And you are sure that the user you are authenticating with has read access for the account you are trying to access?

Comment: I have an MCC manager account with the permissions, and I want to read his clients campaign info. I can only read from a certain one for some reason I cant figure out

Comment: USER_PERMISSION_DENIED User doesn't have permission to access customer.   Double check the user you are authenticating with then double check the customer number you are using.

Comment: Yeah I know, but why would I have access to another client from the SAME account? it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: my guess because you have a type-o in your customer id :)

Comment: Well, that could have been right, but I already tried like 7 different customer id's and went back to the working one again.

Comment: login to the website using the account you are using to authenticate and double check then.  I have several accounts I have been known to use the wrong one.

Comment: I tried writing a wrong customer ID, it just throws CUSTOMER_NOT_FOUND. Its definitely an authorization issue